# Struct and string generic constraint on class level

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, generic-constraints

Hi is there any workaround on creating a class that has both struct and string as a generic constraint?

```
public class AutoEncryptor<T> where T : struct, string {
{
      private T? _value;

      // codes removed for brevity
}
```

My goal is to save myself from the hassle of creating duplicate methods with the same structure but the difference is, the other one accepts a string and the other one accepts struct (value types).

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Even if you could it wouldn't make sense to have the type `string?`.

Comment: yup, I was hoping if there was any workaround, let me rephrase my question. :)

Comment: Try an abstract generic base class and specialize down to separate `string` and `struct` derived types.

Comment: would you mind providing a brief sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The best approach is to use an abstract generic base class and specialize for `string` and `struct`.

```
public abstract class AutoEncryptorBase<T>
{
    protected T _value;
}

public class AutoEncryptor<T> : AutoEncryptorBase<T?> where T : struct
{
}

public class TextAutoEncryptor : AutoEncryptorBase<string>
{
}
```